# input the number and find the largest and lowest number using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, typescript, if-statement

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function largest() {
    var num1, num2;
    num1 = Number(document.getElementById("N").value);
    num2 = Number(document.getElementById("M").value);
    if (num1 > num2) {
      window.alert(num1 + "-is largest");
    } else if (num2 > num1) {
      window.alert(num2 + "-is largest");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're wanting to complete the code above so that the `largest()` function can be called to identify the largest number between inputs with `id="N"` and `id="M"`.

One approach might be to introduce a `<button>` element, and use jQuery to bind a `click()` handler to it which would call `largest()` like so:

```js
function largest() {
  var num1, num2;

  /* Update to use jQuery style selectors */
  num1 = Number($("#N").val());
  num2 = Number($("#M").val());

  if (num1 > num2) {
    window.alert(num1 + " from N is largest and " + num2 + " from M is lowest");
  } else if (num2 > num1) {
    window.alert(num2 + " from M is largest and " + num1 + " from N is lowest");
  }
}

/* Get the find-largest button, and add a click event listener which calls the
largest() function */
$("#find-largest").click(function() {

  /* Call the largest() function */
  largest();

  /* Prevent the buttons default behavior */
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  <label>Number N:</label>
  <input id="N" type="number" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Number M:</label>
  <input id="M" type="number" />
</div>

<!-- Add a button which when clicked calls largest() function -->
<div>
  <button id="find-largest">Find largest</button>
</div>
```

Comment: but i need also find the lowest , sory if my code if not perfect i need to input a 2 number  and show the largest and lowest

Comment: @BenglennDagala not a problem - so you want to show an alert that displays which is the lowest, and which is the highest value?

Comment: yes sir  ive hardly thinking only the largest will show